# Emberjs-1.0.0-rc.6 click to dynamically add more or multiple input fields

Tags: jquery, forms, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to create a form where uses can click a button to add additional input fields. I have created a partialy working here **[jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkJwA/)** and the entire code in the **jsfiddle** is pased below:

I have 3 problems:

1. This adds a textfield but is not using ember bindings **$("#addField").append('
   ')**. When I try to the version that relies on handlebars I means this: ** $("#addField").append('{{textArea value=name}}
   ')**, instead of the output being a **textArea**, I get just **{{textArea value=name}}**
2. Since the added fields will be essentially thesame field as the ones in the form already, how do I ensure anything typed into it is distinct to that field. In the attached because the textfield input and textArea tags have **value=name**, anything I type in the textfield will appear in the textArea. I know this qwill apply even if I use **valueBinding=controller.name** or if is the views property with **valueBinding=view.name**. How do I keep the value of each additional input field added with a click unique to it.

**The entire code in the jsfiddle**

```
 App = Ember.Application.create();

 App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application',
  attributeBindings: ['id'],
  id: "addField",

  moreFields: function(){
    $("#addField").append('<input type="text"  value=name /><br/>');

    $("#addField").append('{{textArea value=name}}<br/>');  
  }

});
```

The template:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='application'>
    <h1> Hello</h1>
    {{input value=name}}
    <br/>
    {{textarea value=name}}
    <br/>
   {{input type=checkbox checked=isActive}}
   <br/>

  <button {{action 'moreFields' target='view'}}> click for more field </button>
   <br/>
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Here is a jquery based demo by someone else, demonstrating what I hope to achieve, that is what you type into each new field you add remaining distinct: **http://jsfiddle.net/qBURS/2/**

**working solution**:

Augmented the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkJwA/3/)** provided by **Selva-G**'. Added the **removeFields() method** that removes any added fields and  a **save() method** that just logs the content we intend to pass via the submitted form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use raw jQuery like this. Just try to loop over an array to draw your form elements. When you want to add more fields , just push the content to the array. Emberjs is smart enough to detect the changes to draw your new fields.. In you hbs ,

```
   {{#each view.content}}
    {{input value=name}}
    {{textarea value=name}}
   {{input type=checkbox checked=isActive}}
  {{/each}}
```

When you click more fields just update the content array like

```
        this.get('content').pushObject({name: ''});
```

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkJwA/1/)

Hope this helps

Comment: How to make a table colums editable on clicking it? Also adding another row to add content to table?