# Dynamically add input field to Ember template/route/view, update model with data

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am very new to Ember and had a question on dynamic elements.
I was wondering how to dynamically add input fields to my ember template/model controlled by a button click. Then have that info be able to update on the model.

I know how to handle if its static. Im familiar with updating controller with action events and writing functions to handle them. I have not modified the view on an action before.

logic and keywords are welcomed, I do not need exact code however it will be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OOOOOOOOOOK after hours of fail i finally got what I needed, understanding ember deprecations was helpful ha. However, I am not sure if this is the best/proper way to handle. Can someone please let me know if there is a better alternative.

The functionality for this is: On click save data from input then add another input, while still showing prior data.

I have a model that holds a temp value and an array.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model:function(){
    return {singleVal:'',images:[]}
}
})
```

I have a template that displays a blank input which the value is always pointing to the model temp value. It also loops the model.images and displays any data if there. Since its written with an #each it is updated whenever the model changes :)

```
 {{#each model.images as |info|}}
  <label>image:</label>
  {{input value=info}}<br/>
{{/each}}

image {{input value=model.singleVal}}<br/><br/>
<button {{action "addField"}}>ADD INPUT FIELD</button>
```

The controller listens for a click. Then just adds the temp value to the images array in the model. It then clears out the temp variable so it wont show on re render.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
actions:{
    addField:function(){
        console.log(this.model.singleVal);
        this.model['images'].addObject(this.model.singleVal);
        this.set('model.singleVal','')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: FWIW it'd probably be better to open another question with this – or – edit your original question.

Comment: I'm not sure what warnings you were getting, but here's a version of your code above using ember 2.2.0 and ember syntax (note the use of `get()` and `set()`): https://ember-twiddle.com/e44bcb878f3e793f4b8d?numColumns=1&openFiles=application.route.js%2C

Comment: Hey @patrickberkeley thank you for setting up my project on ember-twiddle like that! I see and like the use of get() and set(). I actually thought about setting that val in the controller because it is temporary however, I was not sure how to get that value in the controller. would it be something like {{input value=controller.myVariable}} ?

Comment: Simply `{{input value=myVariable}}`. The attributes set on the controller are directly available in the controller's template. I've updated the twiddle (haha twiddle is a funny word :).

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote anything that was helpful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's outline of how to do what you've described:

**model.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const {
  attr
} = DS;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  someProperty: attr('string')
});
```

**template.hbs**

```
<button {{action 'toggleInput'}}>
  Toggle that input!
</button>

{{#if isVisible}}
  {{input
    value=model.someProperty
  }}
{{/if}}
```

**controller.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isVisible: false,

  actions: {
    toggleInput() {
      this.toggleProperty('isVisible');
    }
  }
});
```

And an ember-twiddle demo: https://ember-twiddle.com/3901bf2bf11c65cff1b5?numColumns=1&openFiles=application.route.js%2C

Comment: isn't this just hiding an existing input? I think the question is about adding new inputs on button click. I think this is what he's is looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/17926116/548568

Comment: Thanks for quick reply patrickberkeley however, I would like to be able to add multiple fields dynamically like how @blessenm suggested. Though that example is with Ember 1.0.0 and im trying to do this in 2+, will that syntax still work?

Comment: Yeah it should work with 2.x. The only reason I used 1.x is because I wanted to use fixtures which are now deprecated.